# Buttons that read a result? [html/javascript]

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to make a game in which you click a directional button and the screen reads how far you've moved and in what direction. I have the buttons set, and using onClick I've set them to read "moved 5 meters "direction", but the text doesn't appear when I run it. Here's a snippet of my code:

```
<FORM>
    <INPUT type="button" value="North" name="n" onClick="document.write("moved 5 meters north");">
    <INPUT type="button" value="East" name="e" onClick="document.write("moved 5 meters east");">
    <INPUT type="button" value="South" name="s" onClick="document.write("moved 5 meters south");">
    <INPUT type="button" value="West" name="w" onClick="document.write("moved 5 meters west");">
</FORM>
```

Comment: I would not use `document.write()`. It won't work like that anyways, as it writes in place. I would keep HTML tags and attributes lowercase if possible, as well. Keeping JavaScript and HTML separate is the way to go.

Comment: what should I use in place of document.write()?

Comment: Nothing. I would even remove the `onclick` from your HTML. You should assign `Element.onclick = function(){}` or `Element.addEventListener('click', function(){})` in external JavaScript. `Element` can be something like `document.getElementById('idHere')`, assuming your Element has `id='idHere'` in your HTML.

Answer (score 1):

Try defining `onclick` event in `script` element outside of `html` ; substituting setting `span` element `.innerHTML` utilizing `.value` of `event.target` for `document.write()` as `document.write()` overwrites existing `html`

```html
<FORM id="form" name="form">
  <INPUT type="button" value="North" name="n" />
  <INPUT type="button" value="East" name="e" />
  <INPUT type="button" value="South" name="s" />
  <INPUT type="button" value="West" name="w" />
</FORM>
  <span></span>
<script>
  document.forms["form"].onclick = function(e) {
    this.nextElementSibling
    .innerHTML = "moved 5 meters " + e.target.value
  }
</script>
```

Comment: Make sure you `return false;` when enter is pressed `onsubmit`.

Answer (score 0):

**HTML** might look like:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns='http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml' xml:lang='en' lang='en'>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv='content-type' content='text/html;charset=utf-8' />
    <style type='text/css'>
      @import 'external.css';
    </style>
    <script type='text/javascript' src='external.js'></script>
  </head>
<body>
  <form name='whatever' action='#' method='post'>
    <input type='button' value='North' name='n' id='n' />
    <input type='button' value='East' name='e' id='e' />
    <input type='button' value='South' name='s' id='s' />
    <input type='button' value='West' name='w' id='w' />
  </form>
  <div id='output'></div>
</body>
</html>
```

**JavaScript** on *external.js* may look like:

```
//<![CDATA[
var pre = onload; // for previous onload as there can only be one at a time using this methodology
onload = function(){
if(pre)pre();

var doc = document, bod = doc.body;
function E(id){
  return doc.getElementById(id);
}
var buttonInfo = {n:'North', e:'East', s:'South', w:'West'}, out = E('output');
for(var i in buttonInfo){
  (function(i){ // scope off i with closure
    E(i).onclick = function(){
      out.innerHTML = 'moved 5 meters '+buttonInfo[i];
    }
  })(i);
}
doc.forms[0].onsubmit = function(){
  // do stuff you need to here if submitting
  // prevent enter key from submitting form
  return false;
}

}
//]]>
```

Answer (score -1):

Your mistake is using " inside the onclick. Use ' in this way:
onclick="document.write('moved 5 meters north')"

You can also escape the " using \
onclick="document.write(\"moved 5 meters north\")"

Answer (score -1):

Use single quotes for the 'moved 5 meters north'. If you use double quotes, it reads the first double quote as closing the double quote in front of "document".

Should look like this:

```
 <INPUT type="button" value="North" name="n" onClick="document.write('moved 5 meters north');">
```

Comment: alright, that worked, but after I did that it removed everything else on the page, and only showed the phrase, how do I avoid this?

Comment: Can you be more specific about what you want to happen?